# JNIEXPORT: getIplImageFromIntArray compile error

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, java-native-interface

I want to take a picture with my Samsung GT-P1000, then edit this picture with some OpenCV functions and display it again on the tablet. I'm trying to edit the sample from this website: http://www.stanford.edu/~zxwang/android_opencv.html

However I've changed the project abit and am using OpenCV 2.3.1

```
if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
    try
{
    Uri currImageURI = data.getData();
    String[] proj = {Images.Media.DATA, Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(currImageURI, proj, null, null, null);
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(proj[0]);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    mCurrentImagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentImagePath);
    Log.i(TAG, mCurrentImagePath);
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    opencv.setSourceImage(pixels, width, height);
    ......
    <some more irrelevant Java code>
    ....
```

The sample project I'm using uses a JNIEXPORT JNICALL to load the bitmap as an IplImage so it's usable to edit with OpenCV. The code is listed below. However when I try to use ndk-build to compile the whole thing i get an error saying: **../jni_part.cpp:28: undefined reference to 'getIplImageFromIntArray'.** Does this mean I'm missing an import in my .cpp file or somethign else? I tried to google with 'getIplImageFromIntArray' but can't find any help. Can someone explain to me what is going wrong?

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
    #endif

IplImage * pImage = NULL
IplImage * loadpixels(int * pixels, int width, int height);
IplImage * getIplImageFromIntArray
    (JNIEnv* env, jintArray array_data, jint width, jint height);

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_org_opencv_example_pruts_Test1OpenCV_setSourceImage
    (JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz, jintArray photo_data, jint width, jint height) 
{
    if(pImage != NULL)
    {
        cvReleaseImage(&pImage);
        pImage = NULL;
    }
    pImage = getIplImageFromIntArray(env, photo_data, width, height);

        if(pImage == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should just have knowledge of how to use jni.
the code is Okay.
when you use these jni code in your project , you should modify the name of jni functions .
jni functions should have a prefix like Java_com_your_package_function.

replace edu_stanford_android with com_your_package will be resolve your problem

Comment: I accidentally missed one line of code in the .cpp file which I've added now. However with this prefix you mentioned, I'm still getting the same error as mentioned in my question. Do you happen to have another suggestion for this problem?